# Avatar proportions are broken on suggested edits tool page

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, 10k-tools, profile-picture, russian-stackoverflow

[On suggested edits tool page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits?page=1&tab=approved&filter=all) I found a user avatar whose proportions are broken:

> [image: oblated]

In this case [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPJV4.jpg?s=40&g=1) (not square sized) is scaled to square.

Avatar on the [user profile page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220571/vadim-ovchinnikov?tab=topactivity) has correct proportions:

> [image]

Comment: The bug is asking imgur for 40x40 thumbnail, which does not exist, hence it's giving the full image. It's also wasting tons of bandwidth because of that. They need to change the dimensions, e.g. to 32x32.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 42 (Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything) is also acceptable!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322455/user-image-is-too-heavy and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327886/profile-image-proportions-are-broken