# User image is too heavy

Tags: bug, profile-picture, imgur

Just noticed on [this user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/451192/cinder-biscuits):

> [image]

Yes, all we know that internet is fast nowadays, but ... 1.5Mb for (scaled) 164x164 px image is too much.

Comment: It's not scaled at all, imgur serve the full original image. Same happens on other profiles, this might be a big bug cross network.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i mean scaled by browser, i.e. on visible size at 100% scale for the entire page.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286457/inconsistency-in-display-of-animated-avatars.

Comment: Browser scaling never reduced the size of the image. That size you see is the actual amount of bytes sent from the server.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep, I know, but since user image here is small enough better to use already scaled (on server) image on (before) page load.

Comment: That's the thing: there isn't scaled image on the server anymore, that's the bug. Most likely on imgur side, who stopped generating the thumbnails for some odd reason, and wiped out all existing thumbnail images they had for that size.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've asked for SO position about the imgur issue on another [related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly#comment1054852_314028).

Comment: That's dog photos for 'ya, OTOH I look [purr-fect](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0519547/).