# Profile image proportions are broken

Tags: bug, profile-picture, imgur

On some user profiles, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13295/lance-roberts) image proportions are broken:

> [image: site profile]

Image on activity tab or on [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/7630/lance-roberts) page isn’t distorted:

> [image: network profile]

The issue is probably related to the old one: [Avatar proportions are broken on suggested edits tool page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297206/339911)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image on my profile always gets truncated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189378/image-on-my-profile-always-gets-truncated), if you download his profile image you'll see that your question is a duplicate of the link I offer. His image is wider than tall (instead of taller than wide or 1:1) so it's resized to a square.

Comment: @Rob Same issue, but not a duplicate. This *was* fixed at some point, but it's later regressed again. SE prefers that people file new bug reports for regressions; those are *not* duplicates of earlier ones.

Comment: Links for 1 and 2?

Comment: @Rob no, wrong dupe. I found the correct one, please retract your vote so the wrong one won't appear in the list when closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User image is too heavy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322455/user-image-is-too-heavy)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think size and proportions are not the same issue, but definitely related.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I also agree it's not related, and following αλεχολυτ's comment seems to support that, as does Sonic's comment. I can't imagine why you think that if the image is too large (in bytes, not dimensions) that it will be squozen horizontally.

Comment: @Shadow I'm astounded that the same (highly established) user would post the same question twice. Or, it's probably not the same question.

Comment: @Sonic same exact bug which is on imgur side: it fails to generate the thumbnail used for profile page, and serve the original image instead. It is stretched due to the forced HTML image properties, too heavy, and allows animations due to it.

Comment: @Shadow But neither of these explain the problem in detail, and there is no (outward) indication that these have the same root cause (these outwardly manifest as three different bugs). My suggestions: either ask a new canonical question explaining the Imgur issue and that it's causing these bugs and close all three of these as duplicates of that, or answer one of these three explaining the root cause and that it's *also* causing these issues, and close the other two as dupes of the one you answered. Again, while the same root cause, as written, dupe closures on their own wouldn't make sense.